# Unity Networking Scoreboard

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I’m currently creating a scoreboard for my multiplayer game. But first I need to list all players in an array. How can I insert each player into an array? On each device it only shows one player. For example, `player1` is in `pc[0]` and `player2` is in `pc[1]`.

```
 NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.singleton;
 pc = networkManager.client.connection.playerControllers;
 for (i = 0; i < pc.Count; i++)
 {
     if (pc[i].IsValid)

     showname.GetComponent<Text>().text = pc[0].gameObject.name;
     showscore.GetComponent<Text>().text = pc[0].gameObject.GetComponent<multscore>().score.ToString();

     showname2.GetComponent<Text>().text = pc[1].gameObject.name;
     showscore2.GetComponent<Text>().text = pc[1].gameObject.GetComponent<multscore>().score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I notice you don’t have a brace after your `if` statement. Is that intentional? Without that, the condition will only apply to the subsequent line, while the other remaining lines will be executed for every ’pc[]`, even if it’s invalid. I imagine that might cause problems here.

Comment: It should probably rather be `if (!pc[i].IsValid) break;` Then you wouldn't want to use fixed indices `0` and `1` but rather use `i` .. therefoe I would also store all the text references in arrays so you can map each player to its text using `i`